# How to match the same custom route for custom edit and update actions in Ruby on Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't know how to set up my routes to have the following effect:

[image: The image]

What I have now are:

```
get 'change_password' => 'staffs#edit_password', as: :change_staff_password
patch 'change_password' => 'staffs#update_password', as: :change_staff_password
```

But it raises error: `ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'change_staff_password_staff'`

The reason to do this is because the path is named **"change_password_staff"** without `as:`. However, I want it to be **"change_staff_password"** with staff in the middle for clarity.

I look up `match` and found `match ":controller/:action/:id"`

But how should I set up this to allow paths share same path name?

Comment: Using the as: value attached to a route allows you to define a method that generates the url in your Rails app. These have to be unique to each route, else the Rails app wont know which route you are generating when you call the method. The get and patch in your routes should match with the same route name, so why don't you just change the name of the generated url methods at the end to be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
match 'change_password', to: 'staffs#edit_password', via: :get
match 'change_password', to: 'staffs#update_password', via: :patch
```

To answer @hypern: I want the route to be clear and simple.

Comment: This will lead to code nightmare after a couple of implementations like this in the future, unfortunately, you can set it via resources as well

Comment: I see, I did have the new routes put inside the `resource :staff`. But it is unrelated to the question, I did not put it in. However, you do make a good point!

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach compared to the suggested answer:

```
  resource :staffs, only: :index do
    get 'change_password' => "staffs#edit_password"
    patch 'change_password' => "staffs#update_password"
  end
```

The `only: :index` is only as an example, you should delete it if it is not needed.